# How can I use Wine in both 32-bit and 64-bit versions?

Tags: 14.04, wine, 32-bit

I have Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit installed. I installed wine from PPA 1.7.28 64 bit. How can I have a second instance of Wine in 32-bit? How can I launch some programs only in 32-bit?

I won't delete my 64-bit version of wine, because some games run better on with the 64-bit version. But I need a 32-bit version for Photoshop.

Comment: You can install 32 bit version of photoshop in 64bit wine. Are you getting any error. You will only get error when you are installing a 64bit application in 32bit operating system or wine.

Comment: I can't install photoshop on 64 bit because of msxml6 (it works only on 32bit mode)

Answer (score 8):

I solved it by following these steps:

1. My 64-bit wine configuration is located under the directory `/home/username/.wine/`
2. Add a 32-bit wine configuration:

   ```
   WINEPREFIX='/home/username/.wine32' WINEARCH='win32' wine 'wineboot'
   ```
3. Add a alias in `~/.bashrc`:

   ```
   alias wine32="WINEPREFIX='/home/username/.wine32'"
   ```

Now you can use both 32-bit and 64-bit version of wine. In order to use the 64-bit version, just do as you usually did:

```
wine Program.exe
```

But in order to use 32-bit version it's a bit different. Call the alias like this:

```
wine32 wine Program.exe
```

I Hope this will be useful for other people.

Comment: Why not `alias wine32="WINEPREFIX='/home/username/.wine32' wine"`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use different versions of wine, I recommend PlayOnLinux. With this you can, not only install 32 bit and 64 bit wine, but also different versions of wine.

Install it with `sudo apt-get install playonlinux` or use Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Is it possible without that frontend-interface? wiht WINPREFIX?

Comment: Probably yes, but I don't remember how.

Comment: It is not unrelated. Playonlinux permits installing 32 bit and 64 bit versions of wine.